# “Who heals all your diseases (anguish?)” Psalm 103:3b

Tags: psalms, linguistics

Is there a linguistic link between the Hebrew word ﬨחﬥאים [“diseases” (Psalm 103:3b)] and חול [“whirl,dance,writhe,anguish” (Esther 4:4, “…and she writhed in anxiety (BDB: Hithpalpel))]?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is best set out in a table.

| Reference | **Psalm 103:3 תַּחֲלֻאָֽיְכִי** | **Esther 4:4 וַתִּתְחַלְחַ֥ל** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Lexical form | תַּחֲלוּא (takhalu) = Strong's 8463 | חוּל (khuwl) = Strong's 2342 |
| Part of speech | Noun | Verb |
| Meaning | "disease" | "to whirl, dance, writhe, writhe in agony" |
| Examples | Deut 29:22, 1 Chron 21;19, Ps 103:3, Jer 14:18, Jer 16:4 | Gen 8:10, Deut 2:25, 32:18, Judges 3:25, 21:21, 23, 1 Sam 31:3, 2 Sam 3:29, 1 Chron 16:30, etc |
| Derived from Primitive Root | חָלָא (khala 2470) = to be sick or diseased (2 Chron 16:12) | חוּל (khuwl 2342) = "to whirl, shake or dance". This word is the primitive root itself |
| Related words | חָלָה (khalah) = "to be weak or sick", eg, Gen 48:1, Ex 32:11, Deut 29:22, Judges 16:7, 11, 17, etc | The meaning of "writhe in agony" means that this word can sometimes be used to denote a state of extreme injury or disease, eg, 1 Sam 31:3; or emotional pain, eg, Jer 4:19; or labor pains of birth, eg, Ps 29:9, Isa 26:17, 18, 51:2. |

Thus, while these two words are derived from different lexical roots, the range of meaning means that in a few cases, their meanings come close to each other.

Comment: Very helpful - thank you.